# WordPress page titles don't show up

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I inherited a site in progress. My client had another developer start the site, ended the relationship with the previous developer some time ago, and recently asked me to continue the project. The site can be viewed at [dealernet.co](http://www.dealernet.co).

Currently, page titles are not showing up on any pages, although they are set to do so. I have inspected the header in the Chrome developer tools. The header tag that should contain the title of the page contains no text:

```html
<div class="entry-title">
  <h2 class="h1" style="color: #ffffff;">
  </h2>
</div>
```

Basic information:

- WordPress version 5.1.1
- Motors Theme version 4.4.3 by StyleMix themes

Plugins installed and activated (listed as required by the theme):

- AddToAny Share Buttons
- Advanced Custom Fields
- Breadcrumb NavXT
- Contact Form 7
- Custom Icons by Stylemixthemes
- GDPR Compliance & Cookie Consent
- Instagram Feed
- Motors - Classified Listing
- Motors Extends
- Slider Revolution
- STM Importer
- STM Post Type
- WPBakery Page Builder

Plugins installed but currently deactivated (all installed by previous developer. There seems to be a lot of redundancy, especially where performance is concerned. All plugins were activated when I inherited the site.):

- a3 Lazy Load
- Add Categories to Pages.
- Async JavaScript
- Duplicate Post
- Easy Theme and Plugin Upgrades
- Far Future Expiration Plugin
- Fast Velocity Minify
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Limit Login Attempts
- Mailchimp for WooCommerce
- Mailchimp for WordPress
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Smush
- UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
- W3 Total Cache
- WC Catalog Enquiry
- WooCommerce
- WooCommerce Blocks
- WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway
- WooCommerce Services
- WooCommerce Stripe Gateway
- WooCommerce Wishlist Plugin
- WP All Import - ACF Add-On
- WP All Import - Link Cloaking Add-on
- WP All Import - User Import Add-On
- WP All Import - WooCommerce Add-On Pro
- WP All Import Pro
- WP Performance Score Booster
- WP-Optimize
- Yoast SEO

The previous developer also created a child theme to customize the header per client's requests (adding the dropdown menu in the top left corner of the header and adding a search function to the right of the menu.) Only three files have been modified in the child theme.

I have tried the following:

- Disable all plugins that are not listed as required by the current theme (see list above)
- Removed the child theme files in case they contained an error
- Commented out the custom CSS put in place by the previous developer
- I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739954/wordpress-php-get-the-title-coming-out-empty-when-run-through-substr-strrch) and tried the suggestion of swapping out the get_the_title() function with $post->post-title to no avail.
- Next I tried swapping out the get_the_title() function with a static string. Still nothing.

The php that displays the title:

```html
<?php

$post_id = get_the_ID();
if(is_post_type_archive(stm_listings_post_type()) ) {
 $post_id = stm_listings_user_defined_filter_page();
}

$show_title_box = 'hide';

$title_style = '';

$is_shop = false;
$is_product = false;
$is_product_category = false;

if( function_exists( 'is_shop' ) && is_shop() ){
 $is_shop = true;
}

if( function_exists( 'is_product_category' ) && is_product_category() ){
 $is_product_category = true;
}

if( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && is_product() ){
 $is_product = true;
}

if( is_home() || is_category() || is_search() ){
    $post_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
}

if( $is_shop ) {
 $post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
}

$title = '';

if( is_home() ){
    if( ! get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ){
        $title = __( 'News', 'motors' );
    }else{
        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    }
}elseif( $is_product ) {
 $title = esc_html__('Shop', 'motors');
}elseif( $is_product_category ){
 $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
 $post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
}elseif( is_post_type_archive(stm_listings_post_type()) ){
 $title = get_theme_mod('classic_listing_title', esc_html__('Inventory', 'motors'));
 $image = get_theme_mod('classic_listing_title_bg');
 if(!empty($image)){
  $title_style .= "background-image:url('".$image."');";
 }
}elseif( is_category() ){
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
}elseif( is_tag() ) {
 $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
}elseif( is_search() ) {
 $title = __( 'Search', 'motors' );
}elseif ( is_day() ) {
 $title = get_the_time('d');
} elseif ( is_month() ) {
 $title = get_the_time('F');
} elseif ( is_year() ) {
 $title = get_the_time('Y');
}else{
    $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
}

 $alignment                           = get_post_meta($post_id, 'alignment', true);
    $title_style_h1                      = array();
    $title_style_subtitle                = array();
    $title_box_bg_color                  = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_box_bg_color', true );
    $title_box_font_color                = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_box_font_color', true );
    $title_box_line_color                = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_box_line_color', true );
    $title_box_custom_bg_image           = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_box_custom_bg_image', true );
    $title_tag                           = (empty(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'stm_title_tag', true ))) ? 'h2' : get_post_meta( $post_id, 'stm_title_tag', true );
    $sub_title                           = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sub_title', true );
    $breadcrumbs                         = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'breadcrumbs', true );
    $breadcrumbs_font_color              = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'breadcrumbs_font_color', true );
    $title_box_subtitle_font_color       = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_box_subtitle_font_color', true );
 $sub_title_instead                   = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sub_title_instead', true);



 if( empty($alignment) || is_post_type_archive(stm_listings_post_type()) ) {
  $alignment = 'left';
 }


    if ( $title_box_bg_color ) {
        $title_style .= 'background-color: ' . $title_box_bg_color . ';';
    }

    if ( $title_box_font_color ) {
        $title_style_h1['font_color'] = 'color: ' . $title_box_font_color . ';';
    }

    if ( $title_box_subtitle_font_color ) {
     $title_style_subtitle['font_color'] = 'color: ' . $title_box_subtitle_font_color . ';';
    }

    if ( $title_box_custom_bg_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $title_box_custom_bg_image, 'full' ) ) {
        $title_style  .= "background-image: url('" . $title_box_custom_bg_image[0] . "');";
    }

    if(stm_is_dealer_two() && empty($title_box_custom_bg_image)) {
        $title_style  .= "background-image: url('" . get_theme_mod('classic_listing_title_bg', '') . "');";
 }


$show_title_box = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title', true );
 if($show_title_box == 'hide') {
  $show_title_box = false;
 }else {
  $show_title_box = true;
 }

 $additional_classes = '';

 if(empty($sub_title) and empty($title_box_line_color)) {
  $additional_classes = ' small_title_box';
 }
 if( ($is_shop || $is_product || $is_product_category) && $breadcrumbs == 'show' ) {
  $additional_classes .= ' no_woo_padding';
 }

 /*Only for blog*/
 $blog_margin = '';
 if(get_post_type() == 'post') {
  if(!empty($_GET['show-title-box']) and $_GET['show-title-box'] = 'hide') {
   $show_title_box = false;
  }
  if(!empty($_GET['show-breadcrumbs']) and $_GET['show-breadcrumbs'] == 'yes') {
   $breadcrumbs = 'show';
   $blog_margin = 'stm-no-margin-bc';
  }
 }

if ( $show_title_box ) {
 $disable_overlay = '';
 if(stm_is_motorcycle()):
  $disable_overlay = get_post_meta($post_id, 'disable_title_box_overlay', true);
  if(!empty($disable_overlay) and $disable_overlay == 'on') {
   $disable_overlay = ' disable_overlay';
  }
 endif; ?>
  <div class="entry-header <?php echo esc_attr($alignment.$additional_classes.$disable_overlay); ?>" style="<?php echo stm_do_lmth($title_style); ?>">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="entry-title">
        <<?php echo esc_attr($title_tag); ?> class="h1" style="
          <?php echo implode( ' ', $title_style_h1 ); ?>">
          <?php
                  if(!empty($sub_title_instead) and stm_is_motorcycle()) {
                   echo apply_filters( 'stm_balance_tags', $sub_title_instead );
                  } else {
                   echo apply_filters( 'stm_balance_tags', $title );
                  }
              ?>
        </<?php echo esc_attr($title_tag); ?>>
        <?php if($title_box_line_color): ?>
        <div class="colored-separator">
          <div class="first-long" <?php if(!empty($title_box_line_color)): ?> style="background-color:
            <?php echo esc_attr($title_box_line_color); ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>></div>
          <div class="last-short" <?php if(!empty($title_box_line_color)): ?> style="background-color:
            <?php echo esc_attr($title_box_line_color); ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( $sub_title && ! is_search() ){ ?>
        <div class="sub-title h5" style="<?php echo implode( ' ', $title_style_subtitle ); ?>">
          <?php echo apply_filters( 'stm_balance_tags', $sub_title ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <?php if( $breadcrumbs != 'hide' ): ?>
  <div class="title-box-disabled"></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php } ?>

  <!-- Breads -->
  <?php
if ( $breadcrumbs != 'hide' ):

 if ( $is_shop || $is_product || $is_product_category ) {
  woocommerce_breadcrumb();
 } else {
  if ( function_exists( 'bcn_display' ) ) { ?>
    <div class="stm_breadcrumbs_unit heading-font <?php echo esc_attr($blog_margin); ?>">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navxtBreads">
          <?php bcn_display(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
 }
endif;
```

My client purchased the theme over four years ago and the theme developers only offer support for 6 months after purchase, so I am unable to contact them for support. I have only basic working knowledge of PHP, so I'm not sure what to try next and would appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: If the theme is four years old and hasn't been updated, it may well not be compatible with the latest WordPress 5+.

Comment: The theme is up to date; the last update was 3/15/19.

Comment: what is your desired output? where do you want to show the title?

Comment: I just glanced through the code, but I found a typo that might be the cause of your issue. Right under where it says `/*Only for blog*/` you have an if statement that looks like this `if(!empty($_GET['show-title-box']) and $_GET['show-title-box'] = 'hide')`. If you look closely you will see that the second condition of the statement uses a single `=`, this means that the variable `$_GET['show-title-box']` is set to `'hide'`. This should be `===` to actually compare the values. Try if that fixes it.

Comment: @Sohrab I want it to display in the HTML I posted above, where the theme should be displaying it but isn't for some reason.

Comment: @Azer I corrected the typo and still nothing. Alas. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It looks like your issue is with the stm_balance_tags filter, what is that function doing? try removing apply_filters and that filter and just display $title?